# Overriding histogram to add elements instead of counting

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

Proceeding from [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/optimized-python-code) post on histogramming, is there a way to override the histogram function to add the numbers instead of counting them? 
For eg:  ls=(0.3,1.4,1.6,2.3,3.2,4.7) in intervals of 2 gives [1.7,3.6,7.9]
Just a curiosity!

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. A histogram is a count of how many of the sample values are in each given numeric range. You appear to want to "chunk" the sample values into sub-ranges of a specific size, and get the sum of each chunk. The sums of the numbers in the bins, with a "bin size" of 2, would be (3.3,5.5,4.7).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that (3.3,5.5,4.7) is what I wanted. I guess I didn't understand histogram() correctly. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `weights` argument to `histogram` ([official documentation for numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)).  If I've understood you correctly, you can do `numpy.histogram(ls,bins=(0,2,4,6),weights=ls)`, though that doesn't give the result you stated (maybe you are using a different starting point for the bins?).